# Outlook Addin only loading on first instance of Outlook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin

We have an Outlook Addin developed in VS2008 using VSTO.  This works fine and loads as expected when Outlook is fired up, both in debug and compiled versions.

The problem occurs if the user opens another instance of Outlook - our addin is not loaded into this instance.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like this might help you - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/9edb5e4d-6696-47ae-a334-be76331f4eeb

Comment: That was it  - my faulty understanding of how the addins work...  Thanks